# Is there a limit to the size of a Python module?

Tags: python, bytecode, interpreter

Is there a limit to the size of a Python module?

It seems to me that the Python bytecode instruction `POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE` takes a 1-byte operand, telling it the instruction index to jump to.

Quoting some of the relevant CPython code from [`ceval.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/14adbd45980f705cb6554ca17b8a66b56e105296/Python/ceval.c#L2843-L2855) (comment mine):

```py
case TARGET(POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE): {
    PREDICTED(POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE);
    PyObject *cond = POP();
    int err;
    if (cond == Py_True) {
        Py_DECREF(cond);
        FAST_DISPATCH();
    }
    if (cond == Py_False) {
        Py_DECREF(cond);
        JUMPTO(oparg);  # <--- this
        FAST_DISPATCH();
    }
```

Does this mean a Python module cannot contain more than 255 bytecode instructions? What am I missing here?

Comment: Idk about Python internals, maybe this is a short jump like in x86

Comment: Bytecode operands are two bytes, not one - and there's an extension opcode that supplies an additional two bytes if needed, although I'm not sure if that works with every instruction.  Anyway, the limit would be on the size of individual functions, NOT the module as a whole.

Comment: Answering the question in title: yes, if you don't have enough memory. I once tried to run an autogenerated script (it was some JS (I mean... a buttload of JS) transpiled to Python), and I couldn't because the interpreter kept crashing.

Comment: @jasonharper: They've been one byte since the wordcode change in 3.6, but the docs haven't quite kept up. They still go up to four bytes with EXTENDED_ARG opcodes, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note: I am no expert in Python and definitely not in interpreting bytecode, this is just what I found after experimenting a while.*

*Note: I am using Python 3.7.3 if you use a different version you might get different disassembly output (credit goes to @dunes for pointing this out).*

```
# module.py
x = 0
while True:
  if x == 0:
    continue
```

Will produce the following instructions: (via `python3 -m dis module.py`)

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (x)

  2           4 SETUP_LOOP              14 (to 20)

  3     >>    6 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
             10 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             12 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        6

  4          14 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            6
             16 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            6
             18 POP_BLOCK
        >>   20 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             22 RETURN_VALUE
```

At offset 12 is the [`POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE) instruction. After adding a whole bunch of code at the top of the file (I just repeated `x = 0` many times):

```
271        1080 SETUP_LOOP              20 (to 1102)

272     >> 1082 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
           1084 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
           1086 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
           1088 EXTENDED_ARG             4
           1090 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE     1082

273        1092 EXTENDED_ARG             4
           1094 JUMP_ABSOLUTE         1082
           1096 EXTENDED_ARG             4
           1098 JUMP_ABSOLUTE         1082
           1100 POP_BLOCK
        >> 1102 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
           1104 RETURN_VALUE
```

The compiler added a [`EXTENDED_ARG`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-EXTENDED_ARG) instruction at offset 1088 which allows for a bigger operand.

Comment: I was wondering why I wasn't getting the same dis output as you. Until 3.5 the size of the arg for an opcode was two bytes. 3.6 introduced an optimisation to make the default size 1 byte and a way to increase the size of arg if needed (the EXTENDED_ARG opcode). This is the issue that introduced the change https://bugs.python.org/issue27097 and commit https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/f60bf5f7d6166735e51c30137ea19d289d393ecb